# Memcached on NodeJS - node-memcached or node-memcache, which one is more stable?

Tags: node.js, memcached

I need to implement a memory cache with Node, it looks like there are currently two packages available for doing this:

- node-memcached (https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached)
- node-memcache (https://github.com/vanillahsu/node-memcache)

Looking at both Github pages it looks like both projects are under active development with similar features.

Can anyone recommend one over the other? Does anyone know which one is more stable?

Comment: The second link is dead now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this is an old question/answer (2 years ago), and I got here by googling and then researching, I feel that I should tell readers that I definitely think 3rd-eden's memcached package is the one to go with. It seems to work fine, and based on the usage by others and recent updates, it is the clear winner.  Almost 20K downloads for the month, 1300 just today, last update was made 21 hours ago. No other memcache package even comes close. https://npmjs.org/package/memcached

Answer (score 14):

At the moment of writing this, the project [3rd-Eden/node-memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached) doesn't seem to be stable, according to github issue list. (e.g. [see issue #46](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached/issues/46)) Moreover I found it's code quite hard to read (and thus hard to update), so I wouldn't suggest using it in your projects.

The second project, [elbart/node-memcache](https://github.com/elbart/node-memcache), seems to work fine , and I feel good about the way it's source code is written. So If I were to choose between only this two options, I would prefer using the [elbart/node-memcache](https://github.com/elbart/node-memcache).

But as of now, both projects suffer from the problem of storing BLOBs. There's an [opened issue](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached/issues/48) for the [3rd-Eden/node-memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached) project, and the [elbart/node-memcache](https://github.com/elbart/node-memcache) simply doesn't support the option. (it would be fair to add that there's a [fork](https://github.com/ddopson/node-memcache) of the project that is said to add option of storing BLOBs, but I haven't tried it)

So if you need to store BLOBs (e.g. images) in memcached, I suggest using [overclocked/mc](https://github.com/overclocked/mc) module. I'm using it now in my project and have no problems with it. It has nice documentation, it's highly-customizable, but still easy-to-use. And at the moment it seems to be the only module that works fine with BLOBs storing and retrieving.

Comment: Since you wrote this answer the https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached module has come a long way. Documentation has improved substantially and stability is superb. might be worth giving it a second chance.

Answer (score 5):

The best way I know of to see which modules are the most robust is to look at how many projects depend on them.  You can find this on npmjs.org's search page.  For example:

- memcache has [3 dependent projects](http://search.npmjs.org/#/memcache)
- memcached has [31 dependent projects](http://search.npmjs.org/#/memcached)

... and in the latter, I see connect-memcached, which would seem to lend some credibility there.  Thus, I'd go with the latter barring any other input or recommenations.